# How to optimize the import of swfs in the preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash

I work on a big Flash project as the web backend guy that delivers all the files and assets to the main application SWF. Our last, really big packet of data are all the assets and sounds contained in swf files that are imported during the preloader.

Are there any ways to optimize this process in any way?

I'm really looking for ideas in any direction, no matter if its in the swf, the process of loading and so on. Also I look for solutions for the first time load (empty cache) and for consequent loads (prefilled cache).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few tips for file optimization:

- Choose the correct type of image extension, sometimes gif or png delivers better results then jpg's. Ask your designer to deliver tileable, scalable graphics whereever possible. Take advantage of vector graphics.
- Use the sound optimization in Flash, so import wave files and try mp3 compression with lower bit rates.
- Load sound effects/bg loops related with user interaction prior. Videos can wait. People are used to wait for videos.

For preloader optimization, obviously each HTTP request is extra load on the server. So reduce the number of swf's to be loaded, maybe by logically grouping them. Preloading the crucial stuff first, then background preloading lower priority swf's is always good for convenient user experience.